# Removing top level elements from a JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have following input json payload,

```
{
    "Products": {
        "Product": [
            {
                "ProductID": 458761,
                "Designation": "CB 024-2001",
                "EntryDate": "2002-01-20T19:00:00.000-05:00",
                "S1": "024",
                "S2": 2001,
                "Year": 2001
            },
            {
                "ProductID": 458234,
                "Designation": "AGRS03/08",
                "EntryDate": "2008-03-05T19:00:00.000-05:00",
                "S1": "03",
                "S2": "08",
                "Year": 2008
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And now I need to transform it into the following JSON format.

```
[
    {
        "Designation": "CB 024-2001",
        "EntryDate": "2002-01-20T19:00:00.000-05:00",
        "ProductID": 458761,
        "S1": "024",
        "S2": 2001,
        "Year": 2001
    },
    {
        "Designation": "AGRS03/08",
        "EntryDate": "2008-03-05T19:00:00.000-05:00",
        "ProductID": 458761,
        "S1": "03",
        "S2": "08",
        "Year": 2008
    }
]
```

Can someone please help me to write a JavaScript to achieve this task. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I don't get it. It already is in that format. Once parsed, all you need to do is select the nested Array. I mean you can run through and delete the `ProductID` if you wish, but that's trivial.

Comment: So you do want `ProductID` in there as well? Then just access the array directly. `obj.Products.Product`. Bam, easy as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: You changed the question :(

Assuming your original json is stored in a variable named `input`. This can be done using this code:

```
var output = input.Products.Product;
```

ORIGINAL: You can do this using `map`:

```
var output = input.Products.Product.map(function(inObj) {
    return {
        "Designation": inObj.Designation,
        "EntryDate": inObj.EntryDate,
        "S1": inObj.S1,
        "S2": inObj.S2,
        "Year": inObj.Year
    }
});
```

This will give you the output you want - an array of objects, with the ProductIDs removed. I'm a bit rusty when it comes to working with object references, but you could possibly shorten this using `delete`:

```
var output = input.Products.Product.map(function(inObj) {
    var outObj =  inObj;
    delete outObj.ProductID;
    return outObj;
});
```

This will change the original `input` values as well though, so i wouldn't recommend it unless you don't plan on using that data again.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I need to keep ProductIDs as it is. Could you please update tour answer accordingly. This will simplify the solution I guess.

Comment: Already edited - I'll leave the original in though, in case you need it for later, and also because I learned about `map` just for this answer :p

Comment: I tried to execute the script using a script mediator in ESB. it works for the above simple payload. But when it comes to the real payload it gives the following error. com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "Product" from undefined at line number 1 at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68) at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92). You may find real payload here http://www.mocky.io/v2/56fc727c1000001305aed1b6. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've just ran `var output = input.Products.Product;` against the JSON in your link, and it worked for me. Try logging the json to console before the line it breaks on, and check that it actually looks like what you are expecting.

Answer (score 3):

```
var first = {
  "Products": {
      "Product": [
          {
              "ProductID": 458761,
              "Designation": "CB 024-2001",
              "EntryDate": "2002-01-20T19:00:00.000-05:00",
              "S1": "024",
              "S2": 2001,
              "Year": 2001
          },
          {
              "ProductID": 458234,
              "Designation": "AGRS03/08",
              "EntryDate": "2008-03-05T19:00:00.000-05:00",
              "S1": "03",
              "S2": "08",
              "Year": 2008
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

then:

```
var second = first.Products.Product;
```

To make it exactly like you want:

```
for(var i = 0; i<second.length; i++){

 delete second[i].ProductID;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this little function:

```js
var a = {
  "Products": {
    "Product": [{
      "ProductID": 458761,
      "Designation": "CB 024-2001",
      "EntryDate": "2002-01-20T19:00:00.000-05:00",
      "S1": "024",
      "S2": 2001,
      "Year": 2001
    }, {
      "ProductID": 458234,
      "Designation": "AGRS03/08",
      "EntryDate": "2008-03-05T19:00:00.000-05:00",
      "S1": "03",
      "S2": "08",
      "Year": 2008
    }]
  }
};


function newJSON(array){
  var b = array.Products.Product;
  b.forEach(function(e){delete e.ProductID});
  return JSON.stringify(b);
}

document.write(newJSON(a));
```

Comment: `let` is a reserved word in ES6

Answer (score 0):

With underscore:

```
var result = _.map(data.Products.Products, (product) => {
    return _.omit(product, 'ProductID');
});
```